# Mac visual studio Error { cannot execute code, session has been disposed. please try restarting the kernel. }

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio, gpu, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use a Jupyter notebook in VS Code. I set up a virtual environment venv where I installed libraries and jupyter. I always did it like this and it worked fine. This code also worked fine with me. But suddenly it does not work anymore. I got this error when I create the list of the `train_data`. I run the code on Mac visual studio GPU. I got this error when I run the code. please any idea how to solve it.

```
cannot execute code, session has been disposed. please try restarting the kernel.
```

```
error in waiting for cell to complete [error: canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
```

**code:**

```
normal_data = []
labels_train = []
img_h=[]
for i in range(len(l_train)):
    file_name, label_i = l_train[i]
    a, b = file_name.split("|")
    img1 = cv2.imread(a)
    ## length of train data = 1260
    for j in range(len(l_train)):
        file_name, label_j = l_train[j]
        a, b = file_name.split("|")
        img2 = cv2.imread(a)
        img_h = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])
        max_val,min_val=window_mean(img_h)
        g+=1
        print("g")
        print(g)    
        train_data.append(max_val)
        train_data.append(min_val)
        labels_train.append(label_i)
        labels_train.append(label_j)
        
print("train_data shape")
print(len(train_data))
```